How does string force us to include gravity & GR?
Some physicists (e.g. Witten) often claim that string theory does not only makes gravity possible, but actually force its existence.
I have studied an introduction to string theory (mainly from Polchinski's) but I don't see where this claim comes from.
Is there any specific calculation that they refer to?

This question is similar to: How do Einstein's field equations come out of string theory?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The simple answer is that the massless states of the string include a spin-2 particle, which we identify with the graviton. This drops out of a calculation of the the massless level of the spectrum of the string. The calculation pointed to by BioPhysicst involving the vanishing of the beta functions gives you the full set of interactions at low energies and gives you the Einstein Field Equations plus couplings to other massless fields.
